# Регулярное выражение для выбора элементов в квадратных скобках вместе с вложенными квадратными скобками JS

Tags: javascript, qregularexpression

Пытаюсь сделать функцию, которая делает всё тоже самое что и JSON.parse()

У меня есть строка -->

```
'"name":"Ivan","age":50,"job":["a",["b","c"],"d"],"color":{"green":"green","purple":"purple","border":[1,2,3,4],"arr":[5,5,5,5]}';
```

На выходе пытаюсь достать из этой строки -> `"job":["a",["b","c"],"d"]`

Перепробовал много вариантов регулярных выражений, но результат всегда возвращается такой:
->`"job":["a",["b","c"]`

Подскажите, пожалуйста - как можно было бы решить данный вопрос или лучше поискать другие варианты решения, без использования регулярок? Пишу на `JS`.

Answer (score 0):

Я понял вашу проблему. Вы хотите преобразовать строчное выражение в JSON, при этом сделать это через регулярные выражения. Это не совсем правильно, так как в JavaScript есть собственный метод `JSON.parse(string)`.

В вашем случае это можно было бы сделать так:

```js
const string = '{' + '"name":"Ivan","age":50,"job":["a",["b","c"],"d"],"color":{"green":"green","purple":"purple","border":[1,2,3,4],"arr":[5,5,5,5]}' + '}';
const json = JSON.parse(string);

console.log(json.job);
```

В `string` обязательно ваш JSON подобный текст нужно обернуть в фигурные скобки, так как формат JSON будет непонятен и при `JSON.parse(string)` будет ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это верное решение, но у меня задача написать сам JSON.parse
т.е функцию, которая будет делать всё тоже самое, что и делает JSON.parse
И пытаюсь понять, получится ли с помощью регулярных выражений доставать такие элементы из строки(вложенности объектов и массивов тоже), чтобы дальше их обработать или всё же лучше искать другой подход к обработке этой строки